# How do you handle deserializing empty string into an Enum?

Tags: spring, extjs, jackson

I am trying to submit a form from Ext JS 4 to a Spring 3 Controller using JSON. I am using Jackson 1.9.8 for the serialization/deserialization using Spring's built-in Jackson JSON support.

I have a status field that is initially null in the Domain object for a new record. When the form is submitted it generates the following json (scaled down to a few fields)

```
{"id":0,"name":"someName","status":""}
```

After submitted the following is seen in the server log

```
"nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.blah.domain.StatusEnum from String value '': value not one of the declared Enum instance names"
```

So it appears that Jackson is expecting a valid Enum value or no value at all including an empty string. How do I fix this whether it is in Ext JS, Jackson or Spring?

I tried to create my own ObjectMapper such as

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends Object Mapper {
    public MyObjectMapper() {
        configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    }
}
```

and send this as a property to MappingJacksonMappingView but this didn't work. I also tried sending it in to MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter but that didn't work. Side question: Which one should I be sending in my own ObjectMapper?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding defaults in the EXT JS Model so there is always a value. Was hoping that I didn't have to this but it's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2):

The other thing you could do is create a specialized deserializer (extends `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer`) for your particular enum, that has default values for things that don't match.  What I've done is to create an abstract deserializer for enums that takes the class it deserializes, and it speeds this process along when I run into the issue.

```
public abstract class EnumDeserializer<T extends Enum<T>> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
    private Class<T> enumClass;

    public EnumDeserializer(final Class<T> iEnumClass) {
        super();
        enumClass = iEnumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(final JsonParser jp,
                         final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final String value = jp.getText();
        for (final T enumValue : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (enumValue.name().equals(value)) {
                return enumValue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's the generic class, basically just takes an enum class, iterates over the values of the enum and checks the next token to match any name.  If they do it returns it otherwise return null;

Then If you have an enum MyEnum you'd make a subclass of `EnumDeserializer` like this:

```
public class MyEnumDeserializer extends EnumDeserializer<MyEnum> {
    public MyEnumDeserializer() {
        super(MyEnum.class);
    }
}
```

Then wherever you declare `MyEnum`:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyEnumDeserializer.class)
public enum MyEnum {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Spring, but just in case, it may be easier to handle that on the client side:

```
Ext.define('My.form.Field', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    getSubmitValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            value;

        value = me.getRawValue();

        if ( value === '' ) {
            return ...;
        }
    }
});
```

You can also disallow submitting empty fields by setting their `allowBlank` property to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I am reading a JSON stream with some empty strings. I am not in control of the JSON stream, because it is from a foreign service. And I am always getting the same error message. I tried this here:

```
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

But without any effect. Looks like a Bug.

Comment: I opened a ticket for that in JIRA: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-873?focusedCommentId=311657